# jQuery Mobile - button style after preventDefault on click

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, animation

On a jQuery Mobile environment I want to change the default behavior when clicking on a specific button, to do so I call `preventDefault()` and do what I want but the button I clicked does not follow its normal animation. I understand why but how can I run the animation ? I tried to change the data-theme to what it was before with :

```
$('#link').attr('data-theme', 'b');
```

But it is not working. Any idea ?

See the fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/coconut/uHm6L/

Answer (score 1):

You should add `e.stopPropagation()` that stops further propagation.

http://jsfiddle.net/uHm6L/2/

or you can see [this Link](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. But is it possible to run the animation even though ?

Comment: @coconut not sure that I got your point. please, describe what you want to do?

Comment: I have a page showing a week with two buttons previous and next, when I click on previous or next I load the new content by AJAX. So I would like the user to see the normal animation as when he got a new page.